# SLDS - Transition Slow - How to fade in

Tags: slds

I have tried everything and I cannot get an element to transition slowly using SLDS.

The SLDS says:

> To slowly transition an element from hiding and showing, use the slds-transition-hide and slds-transition-show classes . They toggle the element's opacity and also reserve its space.

Then:

> Note: To control the timing of the transition, add an additional transition property to control the opacity change

For slds-transition-show it says:

> This is toggled on the element. .slds-transition-hide class is removed and .slds-transition-show is added.

jQuery `.toggle()` does not work at all (changing hide to show) so not sure what the last quote means.

I have tried every way I can think of to simply fade in the div **slow**. The SLDS seems nice but actually making it work is not documented well at all.

**Q** How to I get the `no_api_key` element to *show slowly*?

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="true" controller="GetFeedback_Config_Controller" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">    

         <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"/>

         <body>
                    <apex:outPutPanel layout="block" styleClass="slds-text-align--center xxslds-notify-container" rendered="{!!ISBLANK($Setup.GFSettings__c.GetFeedback_API_Key__c)}">
                        <div id="no_api_key" class="slds-transition-hide" transition="slow">
                            <div class="slds-notify slds-notify--toast slds-theme--inverse-text" role="alert">
                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Info</span>

                                <div class="notify__content">
                                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium slds-text-align--center">
                                        <p>Text Here</p>
                                        <p>Text Here</p>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </apex:outPutPanel>
          <button onclick="$('[id$=no_api_key]').removeClass('slds-transition-hide').addClass('slds-transition-show'); return false;">try me</button>
me</button>
   </body>
<html>
</page>
```

Right now I have resorted to `jQuery.fadeIn()` but I would love to be able to use the SLDS correctly for this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out to be pretty simply at this point:

1. Give your element a class say `mytransition`

   ```
   <h3 style="opacity: 0;" class="slds-section-title--divider mytransition"> 
        Additional Users (Leave blank if none)
   </h3>
   ```
2. Add a style

   ```
   .mytransition{
       transition: .5s opacity linear
   }
   ```
3. In the page add some javascript below the element that executes as it renders

   ```
   $('.fade-example').css('opacity', 100);
   ```

This will fade in the **h3** according to the css defined. modify the starting opacity in the style of the element and the ending opacity in the javascript. Modify the speed in the css for the transition.

I am pretty sure that none of this is specific to LDS and I also believe that is expected.

Answer (score 3):

One of the problems I see with your code is in this line:

```
<button onclick="$('[id$=no_api_key]').removeClass('sods-transition-hide').addClass('slds-transition-show'); return false;">try me</button>
```

`removeClass('sods-transition-hide')` should be `removeClass('slds-transition-hide')`

If that doesn't completely solve your issue, I noticed something further above in your code that you might want to also check. I'm not totally certain about this, but it's worth mentioning.

```
<div id="no_api_key" class="slds-transition-hide" transition="slow">
```

Presumably for a motion, you need a "time token" someplace in the form of `$duration-slowly` that specifies it's time duration in multiples of 100 milliseconds. An example given in the documentation is `$duration-slowly  0.4s`. They **do not list** `$duration-slow`.

I'm not entirely certain there is a `transition="slow"` in the slds css system and if there were, you might need to set the token for it, in order to use it in that manner. Once you make the first correction, if what you have doesn't work, you'll quickly discover if using something like `$transition-slowly` has a default that's sufficient for your needs.

I think it important to add that the documentation states:

> A “grid of time” creates consistent rhythm. Animation is defined as multiples of a base grid.

With the way the above is stated, it makes me question whether a grid might not be required for css animations (and other slds css for that matter) to work properly. After all, it is based on the expectation that the grid system will be on the page, something I don't see in yours.

Hope this helps get you moving towards a working solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of a lightning component fading out:

pageMessage.cmp

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="severity" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="fadeTimeout" type="Integer" default="5000"/>
    <aura:handler event="aura:doneRendering" action="{!c.doneRendering}"/>
    <div class="slds-notify_container">
        <div aura:id="alert" class="slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--alert-texture" role="alert">
            <c:button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-inverse slds-notify__close" press="{!c.close}">
                <c:svg class="slds-button__icon" svgPath="/resource/SLDS100/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"/>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
            </c:button>
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Info</span>
            <h2>{!v.message}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

pageMessageController.js

```
({
    doneRendering : function(component, event, helper) {
        window.setTimeout($A.getCallback(function() {
            if(component.isValid()) {
                $A.util.addClass(component, "slds-transition-hide");
            }
        }), component.get("v.fadeTimeout"));
    }
})
```

pageMessage.css

```
.THIS.slds-transition-hide {
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

This won't work out of the box for you if you don't have the SVG component from the Lightning Design System site. The core of this is you need to specify the transition time by adding a declaration to `.slds-transition-hide`. More on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions). The definition of `.slds-transition-hide` is just one line, `opacity: 0`. By adding the `transition` line to your component, you're saying that any change in opacity for elements that have this class should be spread over one second. `$A.util.addClass` adds the class to the element after 5000ms, and it fades out over one second. Hopefully this gives you enough to go on to make your element fade in.

Comment: This is really nice - an simpler than many other techniques.